# Plant cell question in age 12 science test

Tags: cell-biology, plant-anatomy, chloroplasts

Can anyone help me answer the questions in the attachment about plant cells. It was a question in my 12 year olds science exam. I'm baffled as I think he has given a good knowledgable answer but it wasn't awarded a mark.

Kind Regards
Matthew

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a picture like this one cannot actually say whether "part-A" is a mitochondria or chloroplast. That could even be some random vesicles or, to think even crazier, assembling viruses.

The question is really bad and the kid isn't really incorrect. Mitochondria as a guess is pretty reasonable too. However, the second answer is incorrect. I don't know what the kid wants to imply by "to absorb photosynthesis"; it is unclear to me.

Comment: Hi You've confirmed what I thought but added even more to my knowledge regarding what part A represents. I'm not qualified in biology/teaching in any way but its disappointing when marks get dropped due to bad questions. Personally I think it deserved 1 mark out of 2. The kid wrote the part in green ink as they went over the questions after the teacher has marked the exam. There are some dodgy question s in this test which I'll be posting over the next few days/weeks and definitely appreciate your help. Before my kid goes back to school I'll review them all with him to reinforce his knowledge.

Comment: @MasterSQL  perhaps the kid deserved 1mark but don't get disappointed by such frivolous things. Happens all the time. Worry if this is consistent. I had read the entire cell biology book but I got a C grade because the teacher wanted me to match his way of thinking. I think this community, overall, doesn't appreciate a lot of questions like this. These are not of great use to others and doesn't fit very well with the scope and aim of the site. However, if you think the course content and the exams are not good then you can have a talk with the teacher or the principal or whoever is in charge.

Comment: Sorry to confuse here - I'm the dad but the test was done by my 12 year old :) I was hopeless at Biology at school but kids today tend to get a lot more support and do better (if their parents help them even if they don't like it - lol). I won't be going up to challenge the science teacher or anything like that - its partly for my own curiosity and to help my son out really.

Comment: @MasterSQL Not a problem. I was the one who got confused. However, I want to emphasize again that in this site we don't appreciate a lot of "is this book/exam assessment correct" sort of questions because they are not generally useful to the general public. You can, however, reword such questions such that it is about a scientific query, supported with some research from your side.